# Sending variable in url

Tags: c

Working on a arduino code, but its C code. Having the problem that I want a variable with int to increase in a loop to run with the url:

```
student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=%d
```

The updatedb.php files takes the parameter and saves it to the database.

```
#include <Process.h>
char buffer[50];
int val=1200;


void setup() {
  // Initialize Bridge
  Bridge.begin();

  // Initialize Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Wait until a Serial Monitor is connected.
  while (!Serial);

  // run various example processes
  //runCurl(val);
  //runCpuInfo();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Starting");
  sprintf (buffer, "student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=%d", val);  
   val++;
   Serial.println(buffer);
   runCurl();
   delay(5000);
  // Do nothing here.
}

void runCurl() {

  // curl is command line program for transferring data using different internet protocols
  Process p;        // Create a process and call it "p"
  p.begin("curl");  // Process that launch the "curl" command
  p.addParameter(buffer); // Add the URL parameter to "curl"

  p.run();      // Run the process and wait for its termination

  // A process output can be read with the stream methods
  while (p.available()>0) {
    char c = p.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  // Ensure the last bit of data is sent.
  Serial.flush();
}
```